# Passing user credentials from session to an applet?

Tags: java, http, authentication, applet

I have an authenticated user with an HTTP session.

The user should be able to use an applet to connect with this authentication to a server. It will connect to server via a socket connection so looking up the session is not possible.

How can the authentication be passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way is to pass the applet some secret token and then use that to login the applet again. Try `UUID.randomUUID()` as the secret token. Save that plus the credentials in a map and pass it to the applet.

The applet should then call a "login" URL which expects the token and creates a new session for the same user.

Comment: Thanks - is there a reason why the secret would be stored in a map as opposed to database storage?

Comment: You can use any kind of global variable, even one which costs $1000000/year and is labeled "Oracle" :-)

Comment: Thanks, I've opted to store them in an object attached to the user's session.

Answer (score 0):

Passing usuer credentials from session to applet can be possible but when authentication is basic. I havent experience over that but I think you need to read session object to get cred. info than you shold authenticate on java applet class by getting instance from Authenticator class or you may use javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider interface. If your applet gets a paremeter for holding session objects use it. If its your own applet you need to code it.